# Can you please help me analyse this sentence with an accusative with infinitive clause?

Tags: syntax

This sentence is from "De antiquitate regum Norwagiensium", which was written by Theodoricus Monachus. Here is the sentence and my thoughts about it:

> Northmanni, inquit, de Scythia inferiori (illam procul dubio volens intelligi superiorem, quam nos Svethiam apellamus)

Thoughts:
I don't understand what the passive infinitive verb "intelligi" is supposed to be here. The clause which is written inside a paranthesis doesn't look like an accusative with infinitive to me, so I have doubts that "intelligi" is a verb here, but at the same time I have trouble considering it a direct object here, as there is no other verb here except for the present participle "volens". Or is it perhaps "volens" that takes "intelligi" as a direct object?

Answer (score 2):

There *is* an AcI: there's your accusative *illam*, there's your infinitive *intellegi*, and there's your verbum cogitandi *volens*. “Wanting that to be taken to mean the upper.” (The basic construction, which is a bit unusual and may be giving you trouble, is *intellegere* with a double accusative = “to take something to mean/to be,” like *Hominem divitem intellegimus cui magna pecunia est* = “We take a man to be rich who has a lot of money” etc.)

Note that [the text](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Scriptores_rerum_danicarum_Medii_Aevi_pa/rAlmL0TNnrMC?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA312&printsec=frontcover) is quoting [Hugo of St. Victor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_of_Saint_Victor), the author of a chronicle. Let's add quotation marks:

> Hugo […] ita meminit gentis nostrae in Chronica sua: «Northmanni», inquit, «de Scythia inferiori» (illam procul dubio volens intelligi superiorem, quam nos Suethiam apellamus) «egressi, classe advecti in Gallias […] omnia depopulati sunt ferro et flamma.»

So, the author of the text *temporarily interrupts the quote* to clarify the quoted text. Hugo wrote of *Scythia inferior*, and your author explains how he interprets this expression, which implies the existence of a *Scythia superior*: He thinks: *Illam* [Scythiam] *procul dubio* [≈ sine dubio] *superiorem intellegi vult, quam nos Suethiam apellamus.* “He doubtless wants that Scythia to be taken to be the upper one, which we call Suethia.”

Freer:

> In his chronicle, Hugo mentions our nation thus: “The Northmanni,” he says, “having left Lower Scythia [he surely considers that region to be Upper Scythia which we call Suethia] and having landed with their fleet in Gaul, devastated everything with sword and fire.”

Comment: Could  illam superiorem be a single noun phrase? "doubtless wishing that upper region of Scythia to be understood [rather than what he said]"

Comment: @Kingshorsey Intuitively it seems more plausible to me to have the relative clause without a demonstrative antecedent than to have no demonstrative connection to the quoted text. Ultimately it makes no real difference in meaning anyway,  right?

Comment: Sure, it's pretty similar. I was just imagining how I would use this construction (an admittedly dangerous exercise), and I thought I would use it without a double accusative. If I saw a picture of a dog with the caption "felis latrat", I might comment "procul dubio volens canem intelligi" as a parenthetical.

Comment: Also, I think ille [adjective] ... qui is such a common and natural construction that if the author didn't want it to be understood [intelligi!] correlatively, he almost needed a second demonstrative to break it up. Something like: illam volens intellegi hanc superiorem, quam

Comment: @Kingshorsey ah, now I understand, and I think you are right. It makes much more sense that way, because the *velle* then describes something Hugo actually wants and not something he should have said. And of course it makes a big difference, because the Northmanni in that case did not come from Suethia.

Comment: @Kingshorsey I've updated my answer, although in hindsight I'm not sure my new interpretation is what you actually had in mind. But it makes the most sense to me.

Comment: How you have it now is how I initially read it. Though, to be honest, I am no longer sure if that's the best reading.